# How to order on the included property in loopback?

Tags: strongloop, loopback

So, for fields in the persons table, I can order in the following way

```
/persons/1/members?filter[skip]=0&filter[limit]=20&filter[include]=creator&filter[order]=email%20asc
```

But how can I order on the included model ?

the creator model has name property and I would like to order it in ASC or DESC depending on user who chooses the option.

Answer (score 1):

You can take reference from this sample piece of code :

```
    Person.find({
     where: { id: 1 },
     include: {
      relation: 'creator',
        scope: {
        order: 'created DESC'
       }
     }
   }, (err, res) => {

   })
```

Comment: I can't figure out, please can you share more information

Comment: I haven't  tried like the example you have given, but if you can give the name of models , I can write the code for you.

Comment: the model names are person and creator where , creator is the included model. Creator has email field which needs to be ordered in asc or desc.

Answer (score 0):

You want to order the Person By Person.Creator.email ? AFAIK, out of the box, you can’t. But you can do that through a [remote method](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-methods.html).